# Angular 15: Vs Code doesnt recommend library import

Tags: angular, gitlab, angular-library

I have built a library and published it to a private gitlab package registry. I installed the library to another project in another repo. While consuming the library, I don't get import recommendations to use stuff from the library, but they work correctly when I manually import them

```js
import {Thing} from "@company/lib/subentry1"
```

How can I make VSCode suggest me the imports.

PS: The library contains multiple subentries.